# Toggle between images in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a button, which toggles between 2 images, but I failed to.

This is my HTML:

```
<img id="down" src="down.png">
<FORM>
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Pump" onclick="myFunction()" >
</FORM>
```

And this is the JavaScript:

```
function myFunction()
{
    if( document.getElementById("down").src == "down.png"){
        document.getElementById("down").src = "1.png";
    }
    else if( document.getElementById("down").src == "1.png" ){
        document.getElementById("down").src = "down.png";
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I forgot to add Javascript as a tag. Sorry!

Comment: and i suppose it is not happening?

Comment: check src in `alert()` and then put condition!

Comment: @ketan because you have provided full path instead only image name!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is you are comparing just image name where your `document.getElementById("down").src` gives you whole path including domain.

You need to fetch image name from the `src`

```
function myFunction()
{
    var source = document.getElementById("down").src; // get source
    var imgName = source.substring(source.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); // fetch image name

    if(imgName == "down.png"){ //check image name
        document.getElementById("down").src = "1.png";
    }
    else if(imgName == "1.png" ){
        document.getElementById("down").src = "down.png";
    }
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/68cypz5r/1/)

Comment: I tried adding it like this https://jsfiddle.net/ggurLyg4/2/ to my document. It actually switches to the first image, but when i debug - It skips the second step, where its supposed to switch to image down.

Comment: @Frederikwl Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ggurLyg4/3/) updated fiddle i guess you need this!